# How to edit entry widget value if user press a button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making my own calculator using python and tkinter however I can't seem to  find a way to change the value in the entry field. Let's say once the user taps the equal button, the value in the entry field changes to the answer of the user's equation. So how do you do it?

```
import Tkinter as tk

top = tk.Tk()

user_ent = tk.Entry(top, width='7', font='Verdana 50', justify='right')
user_ent.grid(columnspan='4')

button = tk.Button(top, text='clear', command=None) #button that clears the entry field
button.grid(column='0', row='1', columnspan='1')

top.mainloop()
```

How to you make the button clear the entry field once it's clicked

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the entry widgets? All of the methods for adding and deleting text are documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def solve():
  txt = user_ent.get(0, tk.END)
  user_ent.delete(0, tk.END)
  user_ent.insert(tk.INSERT, eval(txt))

button = tk.Button(top, text='clear', command=solve)
```